# VBA-Excel If Not In String Returning False When Should Be True

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple if statement using the In String function referencing a collection and cell within my worksheet.

```
    If Not InStr(1, MyPeople(n).DivisionOwner, cel.Offset(0, 12).Value, 1) Then
        cel.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
```

The problem is that I know for a fact that i am referencing the correct cell and collection cell. I even tested it with a simple MsgBox(MyPeople(n).DivisionOwner)

This means the problem must be in my statement, but it's simply not working!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think it should be `Cells.` not `cel.`

Comment: Public cel As Range, rng As Range is part of my public variables

Comment: Well then never mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
If InStr(1, MyPeople(n).DivisionOwner, cel.Offset(0, 12).Value, 1) = 0 Then
```

Assuming `cel` is defined as `Range`.

Comment: yup Public cel As Range, rng As Range. checking

Comment: Just checked. Works fine, just needs 1 instead of zero, thank you!

Comment: @CodingNovice you wanted to check if the `Instr` doesn't find a match, right ?